# How to wrap size of div to best suit contents, like on Facebook Chat?

Tags: html, css, width

This is the effect I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is a Facebook chat message, notice how the width of the element is strictly based around its textual contents.

If I change the text I write inside, the size of the `<div>` changes:

[image]

I'm trying to do the same thing with the following layout:

```
<div>Test message that goes ontothenextline</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
  max-width: 190px;
  // other arbitrary styles
}
```

But this is what I'm getting (as a basic example): https://jsfiddle.net/dr76t4t7/

How can I make the `<div>` better suit the contents of the text inside?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `display: inline-block` and the padding.

```
.speech-bubble {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 190px;
  background-color: #e1edff;
  border: 1px solid #bdc7d6;
  color: #4f5359;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q35qmkgx/3/

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure that's doing the trick. I changed the text in your JSFiddle a little, and it became like this: https://jsfiddle.net/think123/q35qmkgx/4/

Comment: I just checked Facebook's source, and it seems that they are using JavaScript to pull off this effect, where the element is resized to best fit the contents inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/q35qmkgx/7/

```
div {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:190px;
  padding:5px;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: Realized it doesn't work for short sentences, wrong answer